# yii2 Create dynamic form from one table?

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have table called project in that i want to create dynamic form for two fields that is users and role.These fields are dropdownlist from another table values.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'id')->hiddenInput()->label(false) ?>

        <div class="col-lg-12">                
            <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'users')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Employees::find()->orderBy('name')->all(),'id','name'), 
                     ['prompt'=>'Select User','id'=>'users']);?>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-lg-5">                
            <?= $form->field($model, 'role')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Roles::find()->orderBy('name')->all(),'id','name'), 
                     ['prompt'=>'Select Role','id'=>'role']);?>
        </div>            
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'synopsis')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">                
            <?= $form->field($model, 'poster[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*','class'=>'form-control']) ?>               
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">               
            <?=$form->field($model, 'promo[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true,'class'=>'form-control'])?>                        
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <?=Html::a('Cancel',['/project/index'],['class' => 'btn form-control','style' => 'background-color:#a6a6a6;color:black']) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success form-control' : 'btn btn-primary form-control']) ?>
        </div>


        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Please anyone help me to do
Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What do you want to do with these 'users' and 'roles' once they are selected from the dropdown?

Comment: I want to make a team for that i need multiple fields for users and roles, and in that single user can have multiple roles .

Comment: Look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html RBAC